# Gap fill pandas grouped dataframe but only upto last valid index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to gapfill a pandas dataframe using fillna. The dataframe has multiple groups so I use groupby as well. The command used is like this:

```
df.groupby(['var1', df.index.month, df.index.day])['var2'].transform(lambda y: y.astype(float).fillna(y.astype(float).median()))
```

However, I do not want to gapfill beyond the currently available last valid index which can be determined using the `last_valid_index` pandas command. How can I do that?

-- sample data:

```
               var1        var2
datetime                        
2000-01-01     baa  165.792185
2000-01-02     baa  166.066959
2001-01-02     baa  146.066959
2002-01-02     baa  126.066959
2000-01-03     baa  NaN
2000-01-04     baa  NaN
2000-01-01     ahia  169.777814
2000-01-02     ahia  171.754605
2000-01-07     ahia  173.194531
2000-01-08     ahia  NaN
```

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom function:

```
def f(y):
    idx = y.last_valid_index()
    y.loc[:idx] = y.loc[:idx].astype(float).fillna(y.astype(float).median())
    return y

df = df.groupby(['var1', df.index.month, df.index.day])['var2'].transform(f)
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
            var1        var2
datetime                    
2000-01-01   baa  165.792185
2000-01-02   baa  166.066959
2001-01-02   baa         NaN
2002-01-02   baa  126.066959
2000-01-02   baa         NaN
2000-01-02   baa         NaN
2000-01-01  ahia  169.777814
2000-01-02  ahia  171.754605
2000-01-07  ahia  173.194531
2000-01-08  ahia         NaN


def f(y):
    idx = y.last_valid_index()
    y.loc[:idx] = y.loc[:idx].astype(float).fillna(y.astype(float).median())
    return y

df['new'] = df.groupby(['var1', df.index.month, df.index.day])['var2'].transform(f)
print (df)
            var1        var2         new
datetime                                
2000-01-01   baa  165.792185  165.792185
2000-01-02   baa  166.066959  166.066959
2001-01-02   baa         NaN  146.066959
2002-01-02   baa  126.066959  126.066959
2000-01-02   baa         NaN         NaN
2000-01-02   baa         NaN         NaN
2000-01-01  ahia  169.777814  169.777814
2000-01-02  ahia  171.754605  171.754605
2000-01-07  ahia  173.194531  173.194531
2000-01-08  ahia         NaN         NaN
```